Generate custom podcast RSS feed from a set of iTunes episode links
Given a set of podcast episode URLs of the form https://podcasts.apple.com/podcast/id123456789, is there a simple coding solution that will build a podcast RSS feed of those episodes with metadata properly populated?
There are several open source libraries that generate an RSS feed based on a local directory of media files, but I haven't found anything that will build a proper feed from existing Apple podcast links.
It's possible to manually parse the HTML from Apple, but it would take some work to recognize all the metadata and then reformat it into a compliant custom RSS feed. Is there an easier solution?
